# Scraping Amazon reviews using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would need to scrape some information from this Amazon page:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07Q6H83VY/ref=sspa_dk_detail_6?pd_rd_i=B07Q6H83VY&pd_rd_w=n4cqh&pf_rd_p=48d372c1-f7e1-4b8b-9d02-4bd86f5158c5&pd_rd_wg=8d6Pd&pf_rd_r=AES6X22PPPPREK5DD60G&pd_rd_r=2a4ff4e6-f8ce-4d62-8106-cffd53838b9e&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyTTZUQzQ0Q05TOVZJJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDU2MjE0Q05HOUFSMkdQTkhPJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA4NTIyNzAxOVZYM1dISEVBUk1DJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q6H83VY)

Specifically, I would be interested in these fields:

```
Author | Star | Date | Title | Review
```

For example:

```
    Gi
1.0 out of 5 stars Unacceptable Launch State for PS4

Reviewed in the United States on September 14, 2019

Platform: PlayStation 4Edition: Super DeluxeVerified Purchase

I'm a huge fan of this franchise. Own all of the games, for both PS4 and PC. Waited a very long time for this game and I'm speechless. You can find many reviews of the gameplay and other aspects of the game, but I'll focus on my initial thoughts and will update accordingly. First and foremost, the performance on the PS4 Slim is terrible. Frames per second is unacceptable for a split screen configuration, where scrolling between screens and reviewing the map and fighting a screen full of NPCs is horrendous. Take 2 / Gearbox couldn't even get the scaling correct with the menus, loot menus, and any text (aside from subtitles) and it's similar to reading 8 pt font on a 65 inch screen. There is no vertical split screen and no other options to improve performance. Missions are uneventful and no concise storyline that enables campaign mode truly enjoyable. In many aspects, you'd wish this game was more linear than it is, but it's storyline isn't inspiring at all. Only after a few hours of gameplay, we decided it's not worth our time until the developers make significant improvements with performance. I wish we could refund this garbage.
```

Since I have never done this before, I was wondering if it is something that I can do with Scrapy/BeautifulSoup/Selenium or if I need an API, though these information come from

```
Author under <span class="a-profile-name">Gi</span>

Rating <span class="a-icon-alt">1.0 out of 5 stars</span>

Review <div data-hook="review-collapsed" aria-expanded="false" class="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content" style="padding-bottom: 19px;"> ...TEXT...</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy will be a good choose for this task.
It will be pretty simple spider which will be able to collect required information.

```py
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07Q6H83VY']

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('div.review'):
            item = {}

            item['author'] = row.css('span.a-profile-name::text').extract_first()

            rating = row.css('i.review-rating > span::text').extract_first().strip().split(' ')[0]
            item['rating'] = int(float(rating.strip().replace(',', '.')))

            item['title'] = row.css('span.review-title > span::text').extract_first()
            created_date = row.css('span.review-date::text').extract_first().strip()
            item['created_date'] = created_date

            review_content = row.css('div.reviewText ::text').extract()
            review_content = [rc.strip() for rc in review_content if rc.strip()]
            item['content'] = ', '.join(review_content)

            yield item
```

Example of output:

```
{
        "author": "Jhona Diaz",
        "rating": 4,
        "title": "Recomendable solo si eres fan ya que si está algo caro",
        "created_date": "Reviewed in Mexico on November 23, 2019",
        "content": "Buena calidad y pues muy completo"
    },
    {
        "author": "MANUEL MENDOZA OLVERA",
        "rating": 5,
        "title": "Perfecto Estado",
        "created_date": "Reviewed in Mexico on September 28, 2019",
        "content": "excelente, la edición es de caja  metálica y llegó intacta"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you @Roman. How can I get these results? I have tried with `test=TestSpider(scrapy.Spider)
print(test.item)` but it does not work.

Comment: install scrapy > create scrapy project (```scrapy startproject project_name```) > create spider ( ```scrapy genspider spider_name domain```)  > run scrapy (```scrapy crawl spider_name -o result.json```)
created spider you can replace with code I provided in the answer

more details about scrapy you can find in official doc - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

## first do pip install selenium

second use Python library dryscrape to scrape javascript driven websites. on this url https://phantomjs.org/download.html

```html
from selenium import webdriver
#the path below  from dryscrape  folder  from step2 
 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\Users\\nayef\\Desktop\\New folder\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07Q6H83VY')
p_element = driver.find_element_by_id('deliveryMessageMirId')

driver.get(my_url)
p_element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='intro-text')
print(p_element.text)

# result:
Arrives: Friday, Aug 7 Details
```